# Updating chart in a GUI with Timer creates a new figure & axes

Tags: matlab, user-interface, timer, matlab-guide

I am trying to make a program that displays live chart data from a broker once in a period. The period could be for example 5 seconds or 15 minutes.

I have made a GUI and a Timer. When the program starts, the first plot goes to the `axes` in the GUI. However, all the updated plots (from the timer) come to a new figure (only one), but not into the figure in the GUI.

Attached is some code:

This is in the `openingFcn` of the GUI .m-file

```
handles.timer = timer(...
'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...   % Run timer repeatedly
'Period', 5, ...                % Initial period is 5 sec.
'TimerFcn', {@updateChart,hObject}); % Specify callback
guidata(hObject,handles)
axes(handles.axes1);

candle(highBid, lowBid, closeBid, openBid);

start(handles.timer);
```

And the function `updateChart`:

```
function updateChart(hObject,eventdata,hfigure)
% Get new data, one candle at a time
...
% How many times the chart has already updated
handles = guidata(hfigure);
k = handles.timer.TasksExecuted;

...

% Draw (update) the chart
hold on;
axes(handles.axes1);
candle(highBid, lowBid, closeBid, openBid); % this will be plotted in a new figure !
```

Any suggestions on how to update the chart at the GUI window?

Comment: to start, in the `updateChart` function, place the statement `axes(handles.axes1);` _before_ the call to `candle(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did the edit. I also corrected the first candle-line because it does not return a handle so the handles.chart = candle(..) was no use. This was left accidentally because earlier I tried highlow which returns a handle.

Comment: And I forgot to say that it did not help. A figure still pops up above the gui and the procedure goes on it that figure instead of the one in the gui.

Comment: I don't have the financial toolbox so I can't reproduce your problem. I suggest opening the `candle.m` function and try to find out how the `axes` for plotting is chosen ...

Comment: You can use any other plotting command like just the command 'plot' itself to reproduce the problem. From the following link I got some help before posting to here in Stackoverflow: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102384-how-do-i-make-my-gui-plot-into-an-axes-within-the-gui-figure-rather-than-inside-of-a-new-figure-in-m . However I'm still unable to update any plotting on the GUIDE's axes. Every trial I made opens a new figure and starts to update that figure.

Comment: What is also weird is that the first drawing (when the timer executes the first time) comes to the GUI. Actually the candle(...) in the openingFcn is useless. Still, without that the first drawing comes to the correct place but all after that goes to a second figure which pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to solve it. Indeed the same thing happens with any kind of high level plotting function. I had to reproduce your problem with the `plot` function and the behaviour was as you described.

### Short answer:

you have to set the `HandleVisibility` of the **`figure`** to `on` (instead of the default setting `callback`). If you are working with `GUIDE` you have to set that directly in the figure property inspector from `GUIDE` (*for some obscure reason it does not work if this is set later in the initialisation code*):

[image]

This settings will let the `timer` callback have visibility of the `figure` children object so the `plot` command will not decide to create a new set of `axes` & `figure` when faced with invisible ones.

---

### Note 1:

The plot was always refreshed in the right `axes` when the `plot` command was specified with the right target handle. For graphic functions which support passing the target `axes` in parameter, the syntax :

```
% infallible syntax (when allowed)
plot( data2plot , 'Parent',targetAxesHandle)
```

is always preferable to the one you were using (setting an `axes` active then plotting in the current active `axes`)

```
% this syntax may fail to plot in the right "axes" somtimes, as you observed
axes(targetAxesHandle);
plot( data2plot )
```

Now reading the documentation for your specific plotting function `candle`, I did not find clues that you can pass an `axes` handle to it, so for this type of function, you have to resort to the solution given on top of this post. *However, if you ever give some feedback to the writers of the toolbox, I would strongly suggest to tell them about this important missing feature.*

---

**Note 2:**

You do not have to call `hold on` before each plot. If you know you will always "add" to the plot, you can set it once and for all in the initialisation code:

```
set(handles.axes1,'Nextplot','add') % set "Hold on" permanently for "axes1"
```

And if you ever want to remove the locked hold, just set :

```
set(handles.axes1,'Nextplot','replace') % set "Hold off" permanently for "axes1"
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you very much. I plan to give feedback to Mathworks about the candle function.